# Git problem with current branch, how to see a difference

Tags: git, branch

I developed some projects with my team, we use Java and other stuff
We just finished working on a part of the code. Then we wanted to push and got the already famous message:

`hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Another thing about that now, it has been a while I haven't worked on this branch. I don't necessarily want to merge the remote changes onto my current work. Nor do I know if I can safely force the update on the origin branch. So the main issue is how can I just see the differences and decide which is best for my case?

I guess the problem might be because we don’t pull some of the versions or we have some conflict on our branch

I've seen this question posted several times on StackOverflow and there are two ways of solution
According to the specific case, the solution is either to

- git pull, so the remote changes are merged on to my local work, OR
- git push -f, a force push to update the remote (origin) branch.

So, which is the best

Answer (score 2):

The best way is :

- run `git fetch` to update your view of the remote branches without merging anything,
- inspect the diff and the history of `origin/workbranch` and compare it to your local `workbranch`,
- decide what to do.

---

Generic actions to apply are :

- merge the remote branch into your local branch (final result will be the same as `git pull`) :

  ```
  git merge origin/workbranch
  ```
- rebase your local branch on top of the remote branch (same as `git pull --rebase`) :

  ```
  git rebase origin/workbranch
  ```

Or you can choose to edit / cherry-pick / `rebase -i` ... at your convenience.

---

If the result of your actions is to create something that isn't a straight descendant of `origin/workbranch`, you will need to force push ; use `git push --force-with-lease`, to at least know that your view of `origin/workbranch` was up to date when you pushed.